# using syslog-ng and patterndb, how do I specify an "empty" pattern?

Tags: logging, syslog-ng

When I receive kernel traces in my logs, the last line is empty. I'd like to filter/ignore these empty kernel messages using syslog-ng and patterndb. Here is the pattern I have so far that is **not** matching empty:

```
  <rule class='system' id='kernel_empty' provider='local'>
  <description></description>
    <patterns>
      <pattern></pattern>
    </patterns>
  </rule>
```

How do I exclude these empty kernel messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add an empty line (or a line-break) to the pattern.
For example,

```
<patterns>
  <pattern>
</pattern>
</patterns>
```

Comment: You'll have to wrap XML tags in a {code} block, or the system will hide it :)